# How to delete / update selected element with cascade in Form?

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a table called Platformer that has data like this:

```
 GameID  Bits    Developer   IsSideScroller
   1      64      Nintendo      Yes
   2      64      Sega          Yes
```

I have a Form that holds Game data like this:

```
GameID  Type
```

The `RecordSource` for this Form is a `SELECT GameID FROM Games`

In this Form, Type is a Combo Box and the options are `Platformer, Shooter, RPG`

The Game Form, with all data filled out would look like this:

```
GameID  Type
  1     Platformer
  2     Platformer
  3     RPG
  4     Shooter
  5     RPG
```

I have another Form called Platformer that should be linked to the Platformer table. I only want to display data associated with Platformers here.

When I add a Game to the Game Form and assign it as Platformer, the functionality works, but when I actually try and grab the Selected Row, I am not able to detect the correct one.

For example, if I wanted to change the Type to GameID 4 in the Game Form to a Platformer, then it should be logged to the Platformer table. Similarly, if I were to change the Type of GameID 2 to RPG then it should remove this instance from the Platformer table.

I am tinkering with Access but I am not able to grab the whole selected row and make the cascading effect. I have a relationship set-up with GameID.

I hope I am clear with my request and that someone can help me. I would appreciate it.

Comment: When I actually try and grab the Selected Row, I am not able to detect the correct one.  How do you  do this?

Comment: So your goal is to push any updates/new entries made with the form to the access database?

Comment: Yes @Marcucciboy2